# Variadic templates not compiling in MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, templates

Trying to compile the following code snippet:
This code is clearly using C++11 feature and been described in The C++ Programming Language book §3.4.4

```
template<typename T>
void g(T x)
{
    std::cout << x << " ";
}

template<typename T, typename... Tail>
void f(T head, Tail... tail) {
    g(head); // do something to head
    f(tail...); // tr y again with tail
}

void f() {}

int main()
{
    f(1, "Lol", 5);
    getchar();
}
```

VS17 output :

> C2672 'f': no matching overloaded function found  Line:21
>
> 'void f(T,Tail...)': expects 2 arguments - 0 provided Line:19

any ideas ?

Comment: Your template argument `tail` has the same name as the function argument `tail`. I'm pretty sure that's not valid C++ (especially when you later try to unpack the argument in `f`), and it seems like you actually managed to trip up the compiler doing that. Regardless of whether or not it's technically valid or not, it's probably going to be fixed by changing the name.

Comment: Good point i changed the code to Tail and still not working giving this error:'void f(T,Tail...)': expects 2 arguments - 0 provided // f no matching overloaded function found

Comment: Yes... think about what happens to `f(tail...)` if `tail` is empty.

Comment: Also, please update the question if that's your actual question now, otherwise we'll have to close this one as being a typo.

Comment: Old edit sorry! check it now.

Comment: @Cubic is correct, at some point `tail... ` is empty, and you call `f(tail... )`, which fails since `f` needs at least one parameter. Add `void f() { }` above your function and this solves your problem.

Comment: That solve the problem thanks!! I forgot that when its empty and f is defined after so it basically undefined..Forgot some basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three things incorrect here.

1. `tail` argument shadows template name `tail`
2. No viable function to handle base case of recursive call to `f()`
3. `f()` must be defined before the other `f(...)` because advanced function lookup doesn't take place in such recursive functions.

**Solutions**

Change the name of argument `tail` to something else like

```
template<typename T, typename... tail>
void f(T head, tail... ftail) { //tail here was shadowing actual template name tail so changed to ftail
    g(head); // do something to head
    f(ftail...); // try again with tail
}
```

When you make a recursive call to `f()` there comes a time when no value is passed to `f(..)` because every recursive call will decrease the number of arguments passed by 1.

So let's say you started with `f(1, "Lol", 2)`, internally the recursive call is made to `f("Lol", 2)` this inturns makes a call `f(2)` which calls `f()`, but your function `f` expects at least 1 parameter. Hence the error

To resolve this , Simply overload the `f` for base case scenario with no argument like

```
void f(){
    //last recursive call made
}
```

Here is the complete code

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
void g(T x)
{
    std::cout << x << " ";
}

void f(){ }

template<typename T, typename... tail>
void f(T head, tail... ftail) {
    g(head); // do something to head
    f(ftail...); // try again with tail
}

int main()
{
    f(1, "Lol", 5);
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First a MCVE:

```
template<typename T, typename... Tail>
void f(T head, Tail... tail) {
    f(tail...); // tr y again with tail
}
f(1, 2, 3);
```

now instantiate:

```
f<int, int, int>(1, 2, 3);
```

compiles to:

```
template<T = int, Tail...={int,int}>
void f(int head, int tail0, int tail1) {
    f(tail0, tail1); // tr y again with tail
}
```

The recursive call is:

```
    f<int,int>(tail0, tail1); // tr y again with tail
```

which compiles to:

```
template<T = int, Tail...={int}>
void f(int head, int tail0) {
    f(tail0); // tr y again with tail
}
```

the recursive call resolves to:

```
    f<int>(tail0); // tr y again with tail
```

which compiles to:

```
template<T = int, Tail...={}>
void f(int head) {
    f(); // tr y again with tail
}
```

and here we try to call `f()`.

There is no valid call to `f()` visible, so you get an error.

A `void f() {}` *under* the call to `f()` doesn't help here, because in the template the lookup is done before `f()` is visible.

If you want to fix this the easy way, you can add `inline void f(){}` above your `f` template.

The more complex way?

```
template<class...Ts>
void f(Ts...ts) {
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{ 0, ( void(
    g(ts)
  ),0)...};
}
```

which also does away with recursion.  Or in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17):

```
template<class...Ts>
void f(Ts...ts) {
  ( (void)(g(ts)), ... );
}
```

this is also faster to compile, as it creates way fewer (and shorter) symbols.

Comment: Holt and Cubic answered very well above thanks for more explanation!

Comment: @Omarito Added 3 solutions to your problem.